# Здравствуйте, недавно я начал изучать kivy и kivyMD. Моя проблема заключается в том, что при создании MDTopAppBar выдает ошибку:

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Ошибка возникает непонятно почему:

> ValueError: x1 must be greater than or equal to x0.

код взял из официальной документации, также были и свои проекты, ошибка та же.
Буду очень признателен если поможете решить проблему

```
KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
 orientation: "vertical"
 md_bg_color: "#1E1E15"

 MDTopAppBar:
 title: "MDTopAppBar"

 MDLabel:
 text: "Content"
 halign: "center"
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Comment: Скорее всего отступы неправильные